# Explanation of jQuery code with $().css()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$(".GV#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>  >  tr:not(:has (table, th) )").css("cursor","pointer")
```

Can someone please explain this code to me?

Comment: There are several bits of code there, including a big collection of selectors and some ASP. What bits are you finding that the jQuery documentation aren't sufficient for?

Answer (score 2):

This code applies "cursor:pointer" to all table rows (tr) of a particular ASP.NET grid view (<%= GridView1.ClientID %>) which don't contain a table header (th) or another table.

As a result the mouse cursor will look like a hand thus implying that the user can click the table rows.

Answer (score 1):

let's start with the easy part:

```
css("cursor","pointer")
```

This says the object will use the "hand" cursor;

```
$(".GV#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>  >  tr:not(:has (table, th) )")
```

This is the object that will be styled.

From what I gather, you have an object with a class ".GV", and intend to add the cursor to the ID named "<%=GridView1.ClientID%>" as long as its tr (table row) doesn't have a th (table header)...

Comment: Exactly.. absolutely correct.. but whats happening is when i use tbody.. it is not working.. when is use $(".gv tr:has(:not(table, th))") it working.. As per suprotim agarwal e-book there the author explained that modern browsers does not convert gv to tbody but default so we have to do it implicitly.. But no result for that and atlast I try this $(".gv tr:has(:not(table, th))") it working now...

Answer (score 0):

first you find the element with the class "`GV`" then you look for an element within that, with the Id `GridView1` 
the last part makes sure you do not get the table header

the last part `.css("cursor","pointer")` adds a pointer curser to the css.

Answer (score 0):

set the cursor as pointer to that gridview to all **td's** in a table which have no `<th>` inside `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Pascal said, please don't shout on SF.

So,

```
$(".GV#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>  >  tr:not(:has (table, th) )")
```

is the selector. The table rows `<tr>` that do not have any tables or headers as descendents and are also children to `.GV#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>`, `.GV` being a class and `#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>` an id generated in ASP.

```
.css("cursor","pointer")
```

sets the css property "cursor" to "pointer".